# Importing old libraries in Angular 4 component

Tags: angular

I have an old library that I need to import in my Angular 4 component. This library doesn't exist in the Node module folder. How can I include and use this library in my component?

Comment: Can you please share which library you want to use?

Comment: @AbhilashRathod https://github.com/denivip/jquery-openxtag

Comment: Are you using Angular CLI or Webpack setup?

Comment: @AbhilashRathod at this moment I'm using CLI (not ejected)

Comment: @ivan, Just make sure that you've added the link to openxtag.js in the scripts section in the .angular-cli.json, If it's properly injected then try to apply the openxtag to any element from the browser's console
e.g. $('some-element').openxtag(options);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: First, you will need to import jQuery into your project.

[Follow the instructions here](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176)

Step 2: Import your library like this

Add your downloaded js library to wherever you want, preferably in `assets/js` and import in your component file like this.

```
import * as openxtag from './path/to/js/file'
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Added jquery.openxtag.js to assets, registered in .angular-cli.json. Then I've imported openxtag in my component as you had written above. CLI had compiled build successfully, but in Chrome I've got error: TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_jquery__.openxtag is not a function ***.

Comment: Okay, you can also try using an old syntax like this 
`const openxtag = require('./path/to/js/file')`

Comment: I've just added require method, but the result remained the same. Anyway, thank you @AbhilashRathod